# Yammer Downloading with access token unresponsive, issues 401 forbidden?

Tags: api, rest, http-status-code-401, yammer

Hey guys I ran into a weird issue with trying to use the Yammer API's Download URL.
Since this is an API call, you would think that you could just append your users 
access token to the end of the API URI to initiate a direct download of the file,
but it seems that this will lead to a 401 Unauthorized when trying to actually use it?

My api urls are set up as so

`https://www.yammer.com/domain.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/{file_number}/version/{version_number}/download/somepdf.pdf?access_token={access_token}`

Does anyone know why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

?access_token={access_token} will not work the token should be in the http header and not the url after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access Yammer programmatically from an application be aware of the following:

Around December 2013 Yammer has slightly modified the authentication process.
By then the access_token could be part of the URL as described in the question.

Calling the API with the old code results in a HTTP 401 error. By now it is important to transport a Bearer Token in the HTTP Request like this:

```
GET /api/v1/messages/following.json HTTP/1.1 
Host: www.yammer.com 
Authorization: Bearer abcDefGhi
```

abcDefGhi is the token gathered after the oauth authorization.

Source:
http://developer.yammer.com/authentication/